# Is there an alternative and less toxic way to clean an oven than using oven spray?

Tags: cleaning, oven

I have drippings that have caked on to the botton surface of my oven. Now, every time we use the oven, they start to smoke and set off the smoke detector.

What are some natural ways to clean the oven? There's probably some major scrubbing in my future.  :)

Comment: Hot steam? Not sure, but chemicals are more aggressive against the dirty stuff. So no Karcher devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Create a mixture of water, vinegar
  and a spash of lemon juice (for smell
  only) in a spray bottle.
- Spray the mixture on the dirty
  surfaces in the oven.-
- Sprinkle baking soda over the mixture.
- Begin scrubbing these areas with a very fine steel wool until the areas are clean.
- Wipe out the oven with a dry towel.
- Wet a sponge and go over the areas again to get all the remaining vinegar and baking soda out of the oven.

You might try asking this question on the cooking stackexchange as well, as I'm sure they would have some good answers.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a self cleaning oven you can use that cycle. It heats the oven up to a very high temperature (600-700 degrees I believe) for about 5 hours which basically burns away anything that's caked on the inside.

Comment: that sounds like it will use a lot of electricity

Comment: @Walker or gas depending on your oven and yes it does, but I only do it maybe once every few years. I take alot of precautions when cooking because I hate cleaning but every once in a while something goes belly up and ruins the oven.

Answer (score 0):

I used a product called [Bar Keepers Friend](http://barkeepersfriend.com/) on mine.  All I needed to do was scrub.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Green often works. Spray it on full strength and let it sit for 5-10 minutes, then scrub. Repeat as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Citrus based cleaners (not for the gentle relaxing smell) will dissolve the stuff if left to do their work per directions. DO NOT APPLY TO ANY PAINTED SURFACE. I've seen it remove enamel paint down to bare metal.